# How to migrate Lotus notes documents to sharepoint 2010 list?

Tags: java, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lotus-notes, lotusscript

Is it possible to write code in java or Lotus script or any other programming language to migrate LN documents to sharepoint list?

I have a Lotus notes database, we are in plan to migrate from lotus notes to sharepoint. I have completed the design and workflow.

I can migrate fields except Rich Text Item. I just moved the documents to excel and read from c# I can put it into list as item. Please help me is there any easy way?

and

For data migration, I do not find any helpful link. In all blogs and websites, they recommended to use Quest, avepoint and etc.,

But I do not want to purchase any third party software. Please let me know, is there any free software is available?

IMPORTANT thing is, Can we do it in programmatically?

Comment: Hi- a bit of clarification re the programming:  Is it that you can export everything programatticaly, but are having trouble specifically with Rich Text fields ?

Comment: Yes, except Rich text Field. All the other item I just considered as a Text field. While importing I parsed it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can export Rich Text programatically. Depending on how much fidelity you need, there are different solutions.
If you only want to send the contents of the rich text (the actual text) and possibly any attachments/embedded images, then I wrote a tool a few years ago that does exactly that:
http://www.texasswede.com/websites/texasswede.nsf/Page/Notes%20XML%20Exporter
So if I can do it, you can probably do the same. :-)

If you want to export the full rich text content of the field, I would take a look at MidasLSX from Genii Software. According to Ben's site it can export whold Notes databases to Sharepoint: http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/archive/20130724-1251)